# jQuery Methods in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

Just started coding in node.js . I made a few pages (login,signup,blog etc).

If I want an effect where :
 1. I hover over the "News" button, a slider appears down,

2. To modify image in an ejs tag ( eg. <% blog.image %>) (I don't think I'll be able to use css here).
3. To do something if the user clicks a button (or any other event).
4. Right now in my project, if user clicks on "Login", it takes him to the "/login" page.
   I googled "popup login form", most tutorials are for jQuery.

   While using jQuery, it gives an error : "jQuery requires a window", so I used jsdom, but shifted to cheerio (many users recommended it). I browsed the doc, but couldn't find a "click" event method.
   How can I accomplish the above mentioned tasks?

**Note**: I'm **not** asking for specific code for the above tasks. I've done these in front-end with jQuery. I just want to know how to get started with jQuery in node.js .

Comment: jquery is very useful in a browser - it's usefulness on the server is, in my opinion, zero - so I'd say, don't use jQuery for server side **code**

Comment: I agree with @jaromanda.  I have done some Node.js screen scrape-type of projects where I used an NPM package named cheerio ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio ) that is basically jQuery for server-side Node.js

Comment: nodejs by itself has no display of a web page and thus no direct interactivity with the user so it is very unclear what you are trying to do with jQuery in node.js.  One guess is that you should embed regular client-side jQuery in the web pages that your nodejs server sends to the browser and the browser will then run that.  Remember, web pages never run on nodejs.  nodejs' job is to send web pages to the browser and their Javascript runs in the browser just like all client-side Javascript.

Comment: At first, I thought maybe you were trying to scrape some data and use jQuery on the scraped data, but as soon as you started talking about clicking buttons, that sounds like client-side interface and actions.  If you actually want to full-on "run" web pages on the server-side, then you need an environment that simulates a browser.  There are some npm modules that will partially do that.

Comment: When you said, "I should embed regular client-side jQuery in the web pages", do you mean creating an .js file , writing jquery code in that, then requiring it in my app.js(server side file)?

Comment: @eknoor4197 no, he's saying that the things you're trying to do are things that should be done on the client, and not on the server at all.

Comment: @Paul I get that it should be done on front-end, but how can I accomplish the tasks I mentioned in the question? There has to be some way, right?

Comment: @eknoor4197 yes, on the front end.  Use jquery in the browser to do the things you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have used Node js as a webserver and it is only responsible for serving you with what you are asking. from pages to static assets includes images, fonts, css and even js files.

When you want a user to login for example you have configured your **index** page to have a "login" link which brings him to a /login route:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'home' });
});
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <a class="btn" href="/login">LOGIN</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when you do a request to `http://yourdoamin.com/` node will serve you with this index page. But this page is a simple page no styling nor scripting but you want to interact with your page using jQuery. so lets configure node to also serve jQuery with our **index** page:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and make public folder with stylings and scripts that you want:

```
/public
  /css
    bootstrap.css
    myStyles.css
  /js
    jQuery.js
    bootstrap.js
    myScripts.js
  /images
  /fonts
```

And include this styles and scripts with your *index.ejs*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myStyles.css">
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <a class="btn" href="/login">LOGIN</a>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="/js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/myScripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when i do a request to `http://yourdoamin.com/` with index page, node will also serve **jQuery** to client-side because it knows how to serve static assets. ( although you could use a cdn in place of jquery static file )

Now you could use jQuery on your clinet-side code, for example when a user clicks "login" the Default behaviour is to go to "/login" page which serves by backend node but now you could prevent it from client-side and show them a popup (modal or dialog) login form ( here i've used [bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) ):

myScripts.js

```
$('.btn').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var modalTemplate = $('#modalTemplate').html();
  $('#modal').html(modalTemplate);
  $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myStyles.css">
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="#modal" class="modal fade"></div>
    <a class="btn" href="/login">LOGIN</a>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="/js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/myScripts.js"></script>

    <!-- client-side tempates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="modalTemplate">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        .
        <!-- look into bootstrap documentation -->
        .
      </div>
    <script>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are the priciples of [**Progressive enhancement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). as you could see when one clicks "login" we send them to login page but if they have a modern browser (enabled javascript) we show them a modal login form.

Here we done all our client-side coding manually. your **myScripts.js** file gets bigger and bigger and also your client side templates. thats why out there is [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) and other client-side frameworks and tools like [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/), ...

Comment: That's a very detailed answer,thanks!
But in myScripts.js , I have : 
` $("input#submit").on("click",function() {
  var imageURL = $("#image").text();
  console.log(imageURL);
}`
It's not working!
A simple console.log works perfectly though!

Comment: On the web pages, I'm unable to maipulate data, only console.log is working! Any suggestions? Was {title : "home"} necessary?

Comment: What type of data? where this data comes from and how you use them? then we can decide how to manipulate them. please provide a minimal example with your question so we could answer your specific problem.

Comment: I have a form, where the user enters an image url in ("input#image), I wantto do something with the url(seting it as background etc), but even e.preventDefault() is not working.

Comment: My structure : views -> partials -> header.ejs & footer.ejs. I have included them in each template with <% include partials/header %> and they're working just fine. Thought of revealing this extra info

Comment: The `.text()` method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, you should use the `.val()` method. `var imageURL = $("#image").val();`

Comment: Did you pass *e* as argument to 'click' callback?! `$("input#submit").on("click",function(e) { ...`. server side just render page once, after that DOM is yours and you decide on events. then if you need any communication to backend you could use **ajax**.

Comment: Finally got it to work!
I wasn't using $(document).ready(function() {..}) before.
Stupid me! Thanks a lot, for helping me this far!